# How can I call a xaml inside another

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen as main and a secondary with two buttons(ImageButton) and I would like to call the screen with the buttons(ImageButton) inside the main.
As there were several screens with the same buttons(ImageButton) to decrease the amount of image in each screen I want to call this xaml with buttons(ImageButton) inside the other screens to simplify the amount of image.
I tried this way and it did not work.

Main

```
 <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:tela></local:tela>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Tela

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="Abrir"></Button>
            <Button Text="Fechar"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: What specifically is not Working? The buttons are not being rendered, or you cant detect the tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file **Tela** should be `ContentView` instead of `ContentPage`.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
      HorizontalOptions="Center"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
    <local:tela></local:tela>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Your `ContentView`

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     x:Class="App1.Tela">

<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Text="Abrir"></Button>
    <Button Text="Fechar"></Button>
</StackLayout>

</ContentView>
```